# MVVM C# Refresh View from different ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

let's say you are using MVVM Pattern:

- You have **first View** with a Datagrid that shows some data
- You Open a **second View** from the first View, the second View is bound to a different ViewModel than the first View
- **Second view** has a "Get Button", this Button gets the Data that should be displayed in the first View Datagrid.
- Every Viewmodel knows the same static Model
- **BaseViewModel** implements INotifyPropertyChanged
- Every Viewmodel is derived from BaseViewModel

How can you Refresh the **first View** after hitting the "Get button" without having to Refresh within the first View?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Note that 1-to-1 V-VM is not a thumb rule in MVVM. 2 views can share same viemodel. Looking at your description, I suspect if you really needed second viewmodel! Can you tell  what you do in second view? How do you get data on Get button?

Comment: I would either A) create an event "OnGetButtonSuccess" for the second viewmodel which the first viewmodel can subscribe to, or B) if the second view is not very complex, let your first viewmodel also be the viewmodel for the second view.

Comment: Are you using a particular MVVM library? There is the Messenger pattern that allows you to decouple elements and fire events that other view or view models are listening to, then refresh your first view in response. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210377/proper-way-of-using-mvvm-light-messenger